# AS vs WHILE are they interchangeable?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if AS and WHILE can be used interchangeably.

Is as ok to use as in the following?  Are these all correct? And if not which ones are right and wrong?

1. I watched the sunset as the tide came in.
2. I was watching the sunset as the tide came in.
3. I was watching the sunset as the tide was coming in.
4. I watched the sunset as the tide was coming in.
5. I watched the sunset as it set.
6. I was watching the sunset as it set.
7. I was watching the sunset as it was setting.
8. I watched the sunset as it was setting.

I ask because another usage of as is when stating something suddenly happening while doing something else as in.

1. I dropped the plate as I was picking it up.
2. The plate fell as I was picking it up.
   AS feels more natural than WHILE here...
   So can as be used here as well as above?

Comment: Both can refer to simultaneous events, and when they do the choice is the speaker's. However, both _as_ and _while_ have other uses in other constructions, and there they are not interchangeable. No pair of words is ever truly interchangeable in all contexts; when that happens, occasionally, either one of them develops a different use, or one of them dies out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the four setting sunsets don't work. The sun sets, but the sunset does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nos. 5 - 8 are wrong, not because of your use of *as* but because *the sunset* is the process of the sun setting. You would have to say *I watched the sunset* or *the sun as it was setting.*

Answer (score 1):

My feeling (based only on native competence) is that *as* and *while* are possible in all ten examples. There are nuances of meaning: *as* refers to either a point in time (example 5) or a period (example 8); *while* refers only to a period of time, so if used in example 5 would change the meaning from a moment to a period.

You are right that *as* is more natural in the last two. Compare with
"The plate was slowly wrested out of my hands while I was picking it up."